# Find implementation of interface method

Tags: neo4j, jqassistant

I'd like to visualize method chains of our codebase (which method invokes which method) starting from a given method with jqassistant.

For normal method calls the following Cypher query works. `workupNotification` is the method I am starting from:

```
MATCH (begin:Method {name: "workupNotification"}) -[INVOKES*1..20]-> (method:Method) WHERE not method:Constructor and exists(method.name) RETURN begin, method, type
```

But many of the methods calls in our software are calls to interfaces of which the implementation is not known in the method (SOA with Dependency Inversion).

```java
serviceRegistry.getService(MyServiceInterface.class).serviceMethod();
```

How can I select the implementation of this method (There are two classes implementing each interface. One is automatically generated (Proxy), the other is the one I'm interested in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do what the JVM is performing at runtime for you: resolving virtual method invocations. There's a predefined jQAssistant concept that propagates INVOKES relations to implementing sub-classes: `java:InvokesOverriddenMethod`. You can either reference it as a required concept from one of your own rules or apply it from the command line, e.g. with Maven:

```
mvn jqassistant:analyze -Djqassistant.concepts=java:InvokesOverriddenMethod
```

The rule is documented in the manual, see http://buschmais.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.6.0/#java:InvokesOverriddenMethod

(The name of the concept is not intuitive, it would be better to replace it with something like `java:VirtualInvokes`).

Answer (score 1):

It is deprecated. In 1.9.0 version it should be used this command line:

```
mvn jqassistant:analyze -Djqassistant.concepts=java:VirtualInvokes
```

**http://jqassistant.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.8.0/#java:VirtualInvokes**